# Why is NPM's npm config set always-auth not a valid option? NPM 8+

Tags: authentication, npm, yaml, travis-ci, artifactory

Specifically ->
'npm config set always-auth true' in my travis.yml file under before_install: section gives the error in Travis: "npm ERR! `always-auth` is not a valid npm option"

I have tried the following variations.

npm config set always-auth true
npm config set always-auth=true
npm config set registry:always-auth true    // I set the registry beforehand
npm config set registry:always-auth=true

Each of these gave the same error in travis.

Comment: Because it's not? It's not lying - you can see it in https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config but not in https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config

Comment: i'm with you @Ethan.  The changelog here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/changelog#v7111-2021-04-23 mentions it being removed in the docs, but doesn't say why or what to replace it with.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like npm deprecated this config setting for versions higher than 6. Based on the [changelog](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/changelog#v7111-2021-04-23) provided above it looks like **--always-auth** was **unused and incorrectly documented**.

I stumbled upon this problem with Azure Pipeline as it appears Microsoft had updated their virtual machines to **Node 19** and **npm 8**.

The more concerning change in higher versions of npm (v9 and above) is that `addUser` actually creates a new user now, before it was behaving as `login`. This distinction between what `login` and `addUser` do with npm 9, was fixed by simply adjust my commands to the new behaviors.